# Dynamically generate html table with php of mysql records

Tags: php, mysql, html

The reason this is complicated (for me) is that each column of the table is loaded from a separate MySQL table, and each MySQL table will have varying number of records. Initially I thought I could start generating the html table from top-left to bottom-right column by column , cell by cell, but this won't work because each MySQL table will have different length of records, which generate malformed html tables. Do you have any suggestions?

My idea so far:

- Get a list of all tables in MySQL, which determine the number of
  columns
- Get the count from the table with most records
- Create a table with the parameters (# of tables as columns, max# as rows
- Update each cell with the corresponding record, but not quite sure how

As requested, some code:

```
$tables = mysql_query("show tables");

$output = "<table border=1><thead><tr>";

while($table = mysql_fetch_array($tables)) {

$output .= "<td>";
$output .= $table[0];
$output .= "</td>";
$tableNames[] = $table[0];

}

$output .= "</tr></thead>";
$output .= "<tbody>";

//Get a count of the table with the most records
for($i=0; $i<count($tableNames); $i++ ){

    $currentTable = $tableNames[$i];

    $tableContent = mysql_query("select * from $currentTable") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

    //Generating all content for a column
    $output .= "<tr>";

    while($content = mysql_fetch_array($tableContent)){

        //generating a cell in the column
        $output .= "<td>";
        $output .= "<strong>".$content['subtheme'].": </strong>";
        $output .= $content['content'];
        $output .= "</td>";

    }

    $output .= "</tr>";

}

$output .= "</tbody>";
$output .= "</table>";
```

This is wrong not just because it generates a malformed table, but also because it transposed columns to rows...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We need Code to help you

Comment: Are the results not able to joined in a MySQL query?

Comment: you kinda trailed off before you finished the third bullet point

Comment: Please be more clear in what you exactly want to do. How would you know which row from one table fits with which rows from the other tables?

Comment: It sounds like you need to decide how you want to organize your data in the table - then you can work on the implementation.

Comment: @LiamSorsby, yes that may work but I'm not very familiar with the JOIN command

Comment: Well have the MySQL tables got a common field?

Comment: @LiamSorsby yes all MySQL tables have the same structure

Comment: Can you post examples of all 4 tables?

Comment: use PDO forget the mysql extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to my much hated question:

```
$mymax = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($tableNames); $i++){
    $currentTable = $tableNames[$i];
    $tableCounts = "select * from $currentTable";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($tableCounts)){

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    }   
    ($mymax >= $count ? "" : $mymax = $count);

    $colWidth = 100 / count($tableNames);   
}

// DIV GRID
// via DIV GENERATION
$output .= "<div class='grid'>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($tableNames); $i++){
    $output .= "<div id='col$i' class='col' style=\"width:$colWidth%\">";
    $output .= "<h3>".$tableNames[$i]."</h3>";

    $tableqry = "select * from $tableNames[$i]";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $tableqry)) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            $output .= "<div class='item'>".$row["content"]."</div>";

        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);

    }

    $output .= "</div>";

}

$output .="</div>";

$output .="<div class='clear'></div>";
```